# Flutter Webview - How to postMessage from Dart to JS?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, webview-flutter

I'm trying to pass the FCM data from dart to the webview using postMessage and listen to these messages in ReactJS.

ReactJS:

```
window.addEventListener("message", () => {});
```

Flutter:

```
webViewController.runJavascript('window.postMessage("Hello ReactJS")');
```

Unfortunately, no events going through to ReactJS.
Does someone have an idea how to use postMessage with webview_flutter?

**UPDATED**

```
        WebView(
          initialUrl: '<WEB_URL>',
          onPageStarted: (url) {
            setState(() {
              loadingPercentage = 0;
            });
          },
          onProgress: (progress) {
            setState(() {
              loadingPercentage = progress;
            });
          },
          onPageFinished: (url) {
            setState(() {
              loadingPercentage = 100;
            });
          },
          onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController controller) {
            webViewController = controller;

            Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
              print('JETZT');
              JavaScriptHelper.postMessage({'action': 'FCM_OPENED'});
            });
          },
          debuggingEnabled: true,
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        ),
```

JavaScriptHelper:

```
class JavaScriptHelper {
  static postMessage(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
    try {
      print(json.encode(data));
      await webViewController?.runJavascript(
        'window.postMessage(${json.encode(data)})',
      );
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Share code where you setup webview.

Comment: @user18309290 just shared the code

Comment: Make sure that the page is fully loaded: onPageFinished, before sending anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a thinking mistake on my side. The runJavascript method really executes the command in the Webview javascript therefore there is no window.postMessage because there is no iframe.

I managed it the following way:

Flutter:

```
controller.runJavascript('window.fromFlutter("Hello ReactJS")');
```

ReactJS:

(In App.tsx, but over render component)

```
(window as any).fromFlutter = function(data) {
 alert("This is working now!!!");
 alert(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **window.postMessage** in Flutter, just use **postMessage** do the trick for this.

So in Flutter:

```flutter
controller.runJavascript("postMessage('post from flutter')");
```

and in ReactJS:

```js
document.addEventListener('message', () => {})
```

also add:

```js
window.addEventListener('message', () => {})
```

to make sure it work in whatever platform.

But sure, you can use your solution.

Answer (score 0):

`window.postMessage('test')` can be used in flutter, since your web page is loaded, this js message event can work!!

In my case, when I loaded and add the event listener then call flutter event to notify app to do something.

```
window.addEventListener("message", handleMessageEvent);

try {
  window.flutter_inappwebview.callHandler("AppName", "askForGps");
} catch (e) {}
```